# Features list html and php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I want to introduce something like this on my website:

[image: Example of Features]

But I don't know where or what to search for on the web.

The objective is to create a string with the right features list to introduce in a database.

Here is a [working example](http://ckeditor.com/builder) and the image:

[image: CKEdior Screenshot of Features Select]

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: provide a little bit more detail\

Comment: Carrie Kendall why did you edited my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for : [jQuery UI Multiselect](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/).

As stated in features, it includes *Dragging items from the available list to the selected list directly*. You can always write your own custom solutions from scratch, but it won't be cost-efficient and may lead to unexpectable issues (ie: limit cases).

If the design doesn't fit your need, you can tweak the css to make it look like what you want. In that case, you don't have to code any features.

Comment: Thanks its right what im looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with creating your control using the jquery [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#empty-lists). I allows you to create multiple containers.

Comment: its not what im looking for see the question was updated

Comment: because i need to get the items from the right list

Comment: you can modify the code to place the items on the right.

Answer (score 0):

> html
>
> ```
> <select name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple size="5">
>   <option value="1">Item 1</option>
>   <option value="2">Item 2</option>
>   <option value="3">Item 3</option>
>   <option value="4">Item 4</option>
> </select>
>
> <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a>
> <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</a>
>
> <select name="selectto" id="select-to" multiple size="5">
>   <option value="5">Item 5</option>
>   <option value="6">Item 6</option>
>   <option value="7">Item 7</option>
> </select>
> </fieldset> </form>
> ```
>
> Jquery
>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
> $('#btn-add').click(function(){
>     $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
>             $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
>         $(this).remove();
>     });
> });
> $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
>     $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
>         $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
>         $(this).remove();
>     });
> });   });
> ```

Answer (score -1):

well first you want two select tags with the multiple attribute set, see here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

then write some javascript/ jQuery to grab the selected element and add the option to the other select.

Comment: [that is a bad source](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: nope its not what im looking for